# UIPageViewController for images how to keep aspect-ratio of images when orientation change?

Tags: ios, ios7, orientation, uipageviewcontroller, aspect-ratio

I have a `UINavigationController` which is the rootviewcontroller of the `UIPageViewController`, done in the storyboard. The `UIViewVontroller` is created only by coding. The result works, but when rotation the device the images fill the entire screen and don't keep their aspect-ration. And this looks ugly.

How can I fix the aspect-ratio of the shown images?

[image: maybe a litte bis stretched in x-axis]

[image: extremly stretched in y-axis]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set contentMode property for your UIImageView instance:

```
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

or

```
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: Thanks for that help. Do you have an tip for sizing too? Now the aspect-ratio is perfect, but the top of the images is behind the statusbar. Ok I can adjust the images in PS, but...

Comment: You need probably change style of top bar in your UIViewController. Change it from Translucent to Opaque. If that would be still not suitable, you can always make custom top bar using simple UIView.

Comment: Thanks again for that. I deselected "Extend Edges under Top Bar" and "under Bottom Bar". Now the images are sized ok in the remaining screen.